# How to send json request to server and not wait on response

Tags: django, swift, http, post

I am building mobile applications to go with my `django` based backend. I make a post request in `swift` like this:

```
 var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        var url = "https://webapp.com/makepost/"
        url += NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPk")!
        url += "/"

        var err: NSError?

        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData




        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


        do {

            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject, options:  NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue:0))
        } catch _ {
            print ("error")

        }







 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {(response, data, error) -> Void in


            var query = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


            query = query!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("Optional(", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
            query = query!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
            print(query)
            //update ui




        }
```

As soon as I make this post it creates the necessary models in `django` by reading the `jsonObject`.

The response doesn't matter and could take long as I'm notifying other users via `FCM`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Make a post request.
2. Ignore the response.
3. Update the UI immediately after I make the post request.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

like so

```
 //set request variable here
 let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {


            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {(response, data, error) -> Void in


                var query = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)







            }
            sleep(2)
            // wait two seconds for models to create in backend


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.refresh(self.refreshButton)
                //refresh ui here with method that fires another get request




            }
        }
```